# Maven "versions" plugin - how to exclude alpha/beta versions from response?

Tags: maven, version, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I have an issue concerning the plugin versions.

When it generates a report with the goal:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

It suggest is a lot of libraries that with beta or alpha versions.

```
 org.hibernate:hibernate-validator ......... 4.2.0.Final -> 4.3.0.Beta1
```

The issue is that event if the goal of this plugin is to show the very latest versions of each dependency, I don't want to use beta/alpha versions for production code. But I don't want to search manually the last stable version neither.

I've tried the 'comparisonMethod' option: numeric, maven, etc.  No success whatsoever.

Any ideas for the plugin 'versions' to show the latests available versions of dependencies, but without including beta/alpha?

Answer (score 34):

You can configure the versions plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <rulesUri>someUrl</rulesUri>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`someUrl` can also be a file URL. The syntax of the rules file is given in http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html, it may contain something like this:

```
<ruleset comparisonMethod="maven"
  xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">
  <ignoreVersions>
    <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*-beta.</ignoreVersion>
    <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*_ALPHA</ignoreVersion>
  </ignoreVersions>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: Nice explanation.  I finally updated my common POM using this example.  [This commit](https://github.com/jjzabkar/jjz-base-pom/commit/faac44c8a6ca0831fcdd89459628c77363045bb1) shows the implementation.

Comment: Your second code snippet isn't well-formed, there is an 'e' lacking in the closing tag. :-)

Comment: A shame it took over a year for anyone to notice.

Comment: The following ignoreVersion rule removes most alpha, beta etc stuff: `<ignoreVersion type="regex">.*[-_\.](alpha|Alpha|ALPHA|b|beta|Beta|BETA|rc|RC|M|EA)[-_\.]?[0-9]*</ignoreVersion>`

Comment: Is there any way to use ruleset file inside project? I need project relative rulesUri

Comment: It’s an URI, so use a file URI: `<rulesUri>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-version-rules.xml</rulesUri>`

Comment: Does anyone have experience in using this with multi-module projects? Can I specify a (relative) path to the rules file in such a case? I put mine in the parent module's root and `ln` it into every submodule. That works but might not be the most elegant approach.

Comment: I have a property `<versions-rules>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-version-rules.xml</versions-rules>` in the parent and `<versions-rules>file:///${project.basedir}/../maven-version-rules.xml</versions-rules>` in all children. That way, I need only the configuration of the plugin in the parent.

Comment: ruleset has no closing element, and rules has no opening element.

Comment: I suggest `<rulesUri>${project.baseUri}/maven-version-rules.xml</rulesUri>` and `<ignoreVersion type="regex">(?i).*[-_\.](alpha|b|beta|rc|m|ea)[-_\.]?[0-9]*</ignoreVersion>` which is case-insensitive.