# Gradle suggests Alpha/Beta versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Is there any way to stop Android Studio from suggesting early releases in the build.gradle files?

Happens with `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1` (-> 5.0.0-alpha.2)
and `androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0` (-> 2.6.0-alpha02)

Plain IDEA doesn't suggest upgrading okhttp.

Comment: They seem to have broken something with Android Studio 4.2. 4.1 was only doing this if you were on an existing pre-release version -- 4.2 seems to be doing it all the time.

Comment: Seems reasonable, I can't remember having that bug before updating. Maybe related to the 'kotlin version does not match the one bundled into the Ide' message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Gradle's dynamic versions and avoid betas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995517/how-to-use-gradles-dynamic-versions-and-avoid-betas)