# Maven-version-plugin, ruleset, rule & ignoreVersions tags

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, uri

I am trying to use maven-version-plugin to automatically update all my dependencies. Nevertheless, I don't want alpha or beta versions.
Thus, I have created a "rule file" to exclude these versions. Here it is:

```
<ruleset comparisonMethod="maven"
     xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">

    <rule groupId="commons-logging" artifactId="commons-logging">

        <ignoreVersions>
            <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*[-_\.](alpha|Alpha|ALPHA|b|beta|Beta|BETA|rc|‌​RC|M|EA)[-_\.]?[0-9]*</ignoreVersion>
        </ignoreVersions>

    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

(This regex comes from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230903/maven-versions-plugin-how-to-exclude-alpha-beta-versions-from-reponse).)

The problem is that Intellij IDEA makes the xmlns URI and the second xsi:schemaLocation URI red, saying "*URI is not registered*" for the first one and "*Cannot resolve symbol 'http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd'*" for the second one. [The documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) uses the same values, so I assume they are goods.

How can I register this URI and then patch the unresolvable symbol?

Thanks !

Comment: There should be Alt+Enter intention action to fix the unregistered URIs?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
There are four actions with Alt+Enter, but none of them succeeded to fix the unregistered URIs...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The issue seems to be that the actual proposed location `http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd` gives a HTTP/1.1 404.

Intellij IDEA tries to resolve the namespace using the schema that _should_ be at the given URL, but can't find it due to the 404.

I'm trying to find the schema manually (that is: using search engines), but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the actual schema is not located at http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd but here: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd

The documentation (http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) actually gives a wrong example file, but does state the following

> The rule-set files must match the [XSD schema](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd).

This means that the `xsi:schemaLocation` should be changed to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd"
```

In full, that becomes this:

```
<ruleset 
  comparisonMethod="maven"
  xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">

  <rule groupId="commons-logging" artifactId="commons-logging">
    <ignoreVersions>
      <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*[-_\.](alpha|Alpha|ALPHA|b|beta|Beta|BETA|rc|‌​RC|M|EA)[-_\.]?[0-9]*</ignoreVersion>
    </ignoreVersions>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

After changing the `xsi:schemaLocation` you can use `<Alt>+<Enter>` and choose "Fetch external resources" to resolve the schema and import the correct namespace.

---

Alternatively:

You can also tell IntelliJ IDEA where *you* think the schema is located. For example, you could download the file to disk; press `<Alt>+<Enter>` , choose "Manually setup external resource" and point to the file you just downloaded. IntelliJ IDEA *should* now ignore the `xsi:schemaLocation` hint and use the override you just configured.

The downside of using the `xsi:schemaLocation` that points to a remote file, is that the xml-processor will have to download it on-the-fly every time (which is a performance hit, especially if the schema itself also points to external schema's). Secondly, since it is *not* an http**s**, you'll have to trust that the file is not modified in transport. By downloading it beforehand, you can inspect the file, place it in a trusted location and use that *known* version.